# All links give 404 Not Found when I moved the Drupal site to a web host

Tags: php, drupal, web-hosting, drupal-8, host

I uploaded my drupal site on the web-host. I use a web host:**aiwebhost.com**. But when I click any link on my site I get error:

---

## Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

I found a similar question on stackoverflow:
[Drupal 8.5.4 all links give 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843155/drupal-8-5-4-all-links-give-404-not-found)
But there the question concerned the local server. But I have error on the web host

In local server my site working well

How to fix it?

Comment: Your First port of call is to view the error logs on the host.

Comment: Did you try the answers in the stack question you linked to? The answers can apply to any host, local or not. It would probably help too if you show us the url in which you are getting the 404.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The error occurred because the `.htaccess` file was not added to the web host